# Is there a way to restore previous Google Apps Script Editor Versions

Tags: google-apps-script, revision-history

Is there a way to restore previous Google Apps Script Editor Versions?

I accidentally deleted a big portion of my code in the Google Script Editor. In the new editor, I do not see a way to restore versions.

In the old editor, I can go to File > See version history (please see image)[image].

Unfortunately, this only goes back a few hours.

Is there a way to retrieve a version from yesterday?

TIA

Comment: Are the versions published as a library or webapp?

Comment: @TheMaster Neither. I'm using the code editor to add functions to a spreadsheet, so I haven't had the need to publish it. I didn't realize the library was a thing until just now. This is just the user of the editor on the cloud. I hope how I explained it makes sense.

Comment: Try this api at the very end of [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent).

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your suggestion. I tried that. Unfortunately, that only gives me versions of deployed apps. It doesn't provide revisions to the code. I am editing my question to include an image of what the revision history in the old version looks like.

Comment: If you haven't created a explicit version,  I'm afraid it's lost forever. If you have created a explicit version(which you must have, when deploying webapps), you can include that version number in the api to get that specific version

Comment: @TheMaster I was afraid of that. I'm in the process of redoing it now. :(
Thank you for your help.

Comment: At Google Cloud Next '21, they said that the management of the version of Google Apps Script will be able to be done with the new IDE in the near future. Unfortunately, in the current stage, I think that this cannot be restored. But when the management of the version of Google Apps Script at new IDE got to be able to be released, such situations might be able to be reduced. I hope for it.

Comment: Is this a standalone or a container-bound script?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Yes it was. I've recreated it.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot  What difference would it make?

Comment: @TheMaster I was thinking that one might [use the Drive API to revert to an earlier version](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions) if it were a standalone script. But then I checked the documentation and it appears that's only possible with files that are not google docs (well, the docs state that revisions cannot be downloaded for Google Sheets, Slides or Docs, so it might still be possible with GAS files - might be worth investigating).

Comment: @TheAddonDepot Just tested it. Using script id as file id, For standalone, `{




 "error": {




  "errors": [




   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "revisionsNotSupported",
    "message": "The file does not support revisions."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The file does not support revisions."
 }
}​`. For container bound, ``File not found``

Answer (score 2):

You can try reverting to the legacy editor to access your script revision by clicking on the "Use legacy editor" button on the top right of the Apps Script window.

[image]

Comment: This allows you to see the revisions, but unfortunately, it only shows so many revisions. In the photo above, it only went back a few hours. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Lifesaver, I deleted code, went to executions and then back only to discover that I can no longer undo. Legacy editor helped!

Comment: The "Use legacy editor" button does not show up for me

Comment: "Use legacy editor" button is now longer there, since its decommissioning.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you weren't already using clasp, when you created those versions, you can still use it now to retrieve the code for them. However, this only works if you created an explicit version of the code, under deployments, even if you didn't actually deploy them.

First install NPM, then:

```
npm i @google/clasp -g             # install clasp
clasp login                        # login to your Google account
mkdir some_folder
cd some_folder
clasp clone <ScriptId>             # replace <ScriptID> with your script id
clasp pull --versionNumber X       # replace X with version number you want
```